# Как сверстать кнопку с задним фоном?

Tags: html, css

Пытался сделать с помощью before и after, но если делаю position: absolute, то кнопка находится под задним фоном. z-index не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать это?

Comment: Добавьте пример вашей реализации в вопрос

Comment: @DarthKYL: Автор что, за Вас всё будет делать??? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно примерно так:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  z-index: 2;
}

.button-inner {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
}

.button-inner:before {
  content: '...';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="button-inner">Выбрать файл</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Выбрать файл

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Выбрать файл</div>
```